# Collide Once then don't do it again

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How do I make my SKnodes collide only once? I have an particle system that is appearing when they collide but if they collide again a bunch appears. I don't want that. Just want one then thats it. How would I go about pulling this effect off?

```
if bodyA.categoryBitMask == 1 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 3 || bodyA.categoryBitMask == 3 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 1 {
        print("END GAME")


        if let dieexplostionNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Explosion.sks"){
                dieexplostionNode.targetNode = self
                dieexplostionNode.position = player.position

                // add 3 actions
                let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.1)
                let addExplosion = SKAction.run {
                    self.player.addChild(dieexplostionNode)
                    self.player.alpha = 0
                }
                let removePlayer = SKAction.run {
                    self.player.removeFromParent()
                    self.player.removeAllActions()
                    dieexplostionNode.removeFromParent()

                }

                // put them in a sequence.
                let seq = SKAction.sequence([addExplosion,wait,removePlayer])

                // run the sequence
                self.run(seq)

            }
```

Comment: Two ideas come to mind. Change something about the nodes (either the categories or the physics body's category/collision bitmap or type) when a collision occurs, so you don't run the explosion again, or just keep track of whether you have triggered the explosion with another variable.

Comment: Very good idea! Thanks man, i really appreciate that. I was trying to think of something like this. I will be changing the category so it doesn't matter if it does collide again. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is multiple contacts can happen, so you need to place a check in your code to tell your system you already evaluate a contact and do not want to do any other evaluation.  My preferred method is to reserve bit 31 on the category bit mask flag, and if that is set, do not evaulate.

```
guard bodyA.categoryBitMask < 1 << 31 && bodyB.categoryBitMask < 1 << 31 else {return}

if bodyA.categoryBitMask == 1 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 3 || bodyA.categoryBitMask == 3 && bodyB.categoryBitMask == 1 {
        print("END GAME")
        player.categoryBitMask += 1<<31

        if let dieexplostionNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Explosion.sks"){
                dieexplostionNode.targetNode = self
                dieexplostionNode.position = player.position

                // add 3 actions
                let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.1)
                let addExplosion = SKAction.run {
                    self.player.addChild(dieexplostionNode)
                    self.player.alpha = 0
                }
                let removePlayer = SKAction.run {
                    self.player.removeFromParent()
                    self.player.removeAllActions()
                    dieexplostionNode.removeFromParent()

                }

                // put them in a sequence.
                let seq = SKAction.sequence([addExplosion,wait,removePlayer])

                // run the sequence
                self.run(seq)

            }
```